# Acces to element of array

Tags: php, symfony

My problem is:

I'm trying to acces to element of array example:

```
info() {
'library_code' => "example"
'report_date_end' => "2016-03-15 12:49:42"
'report_date_start' =>"2016-03-15 12:49:42"
'isbn' => NULL
}
```

So I'm doing:

```
$libraryXML     = $info['library_code'];
```

But I have an error:

> Notice: Undefined index: library_code

How can I take this info?

ExtraInfo:

```
public function getInfo(){
    $sql = "select library_code, report_date_end, report_date_start, concept from xml_reports where status = 0";

    $rsm = new ResultSetMapping();
    $rsm->addScalarResult('library_code', 'library_code');
    $rsm->addScalarResult('report_date_end', 'report_date_end');
    $rsm->addScalarResult('report_date_start', 'report_date_start');
    $rsm->addScalarResult('concept', 'isbn');
    $query = $this->_em->createNativeQuery($sql, $rsm);

    return $query->getResult();
}

$info               = $this->xmlReportRepo->getInfo();
```

Thanks!

Comment: where is the creation of $info variable?

Comment: info is a function or what?

Comment: if info is an array then it shold be define as 
$info = array(
'library_code' => "example"
'report_date_end' => "2016-03-15 12:49:42"
'report_date_start' =>"2016-03-15 12:49:42"
'isbn' => NULL
);

Comment: `print_r($info);` check what r u getting?

Comment: @devpro When i did var_dump($info) Console show me the error.

Comment: what is the error?

Comment: @devpro Notice: Undefined index: library_code

Comment: but when u use print_r($info); or var_dump($info); what u get?

Comment: Documentation  related to the issues you are facing http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php  http://php.net/manual/en/functions.user-defined.php

Comment: [1] => Array
        (
            [library_code] => example
            [report_date_end] => 2016-03-15 12:49:42
            [report_date_start] => 2016-03-15 12:49:42
            [isbn] => 
        )
@devpro

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You define wrong the array.

Should be:

```
array(
  key  => value,
  key2 => value2,
  key3 => value3,
  ...
)
```

From: [PHP array manual](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php)

Comment: But I dont declare the array is a return of function getInfo

Comment: Check out example #7 in the manual.

Comment: Done thanks @AntonEpikhin

Answer (score -1):

As Anton Epikhin says :

your array definition is wrong, but you can also use [] (php 5.4)

```
$info = [
'library_code' => "example"
'report_date_end' => "2016-03-15 12:49:42"
'report_date_start' =>"2016-03-15 12:49:42"
'isbn' => NULL
]
```

Looks like you doing some js code instead of php

Comment: Thanks :) I need to be more careful and review before posting